# Type alias for a characteristic function

Tags: haskell

In Scala, we can define a type alias for a characteristic function like

```
      type Set = Int => Boolean
```

In Haskell, how can we achieve the same goal?

Comment: Just the same, except that the arrow is `->`, and a `Boolean` is a `Bool`, so `type Set = Int -> Bool`.

Answer (score 10):

This is almost exactly the same as in Scala, except that in Haskell

1. the arrow is denoted as `->`, `=>` is used for type constraints; and
2. a `Boolean` in Haskell is a `Bool`.

So we can define this as:

```
type Set = Int -> Bool
```